# How to check if the pin headers are soldered well?

Tags: soldering, surface-mount

I don't have much soldering experience. I soldered 5 level converters, they seem to work and look about the same as this STM32 as I soldered.

However, after a closer look I see not all pens 'shine' and some don't have a good form. Probably used too much soldering, because it was quite hard to determine (using too less cause nothing but heating pins which I also wanted to prevent more than needed).

How can I best test if all soldering connections are ok? I don't have any STM32 experience, so I don't know if there is a general way to do this except for writing programs/testing for each pin?

Or is it visible directly from the pictures that this will not work (I hope not).

(btw it's hard to make pics, they are all from the same STM32, the first pic shows soldering connections which are much darker than the second, the second looks more like the real thing).

Edit: I think I know what I did wrong ... since I didn't have much space the solder tip and solder tin sometimes might have touched directly, also during that the pin itself might not have been heated enough. Next time I really should make sure the tin and tip are on opposite sides of the pin.

[image: pic1]

[image: pic1b]

[image: pic2]

[image: pic3]

[image]

**Update: Used aceton/alcohol**

I used a mixture of 50% 96% alcohol and aceton and got the following results: 
It seems to leave some white residue ... wondering if that is a problem.

[image]

Comment: Google IPC610, now it's revision e i think, but previous should work as well. They define all you need.

Comment: There are some cleaning solvents that might help remove some of the flux, which helps us "see" them better. But many of those look acceptable enough for hobby work to me. A few look "cold", but it's hard to be sure. Of those, I'm more bothered by A15 and A12. C15 is "different" but I can't tell much from the pics. Learn to quickly clean the soldering tip, dab just a bit of solder to it, move firmly to heat the target, and then quickly use a consistent amount of solder (up to a point, less is more.) Oxidation is bad and the longer you take the more that gets in the way of doing it well.

Comment: @jonk thanks  ... I have something to remove soldering (solder wick), but you mean something else I guess to remove flux? 

A15 is ok I think, but A12 is more like a blob... C15 has maybe a bit too less soldering now I look at it better.

I cleaned after each pin header, maybe that is too less. The problem is that it didn't work well to head the pin on one side and touch the solder to the other side, so I did it mostly on top of the pin so the solder flow over the pin, that's why something it is too much probably.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum that document costs 75 or 150 euro ... note I'm a hobbyist.

Comment: Google better, there are free versions around

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Yeah, I mean a liquid, labeled for this purpose, in a jar with a brush. (I don't imagine you want to use the old method of a boiling vat of CFC-12 that you immerse the board into.) In some situations, an aerosol can spray is okay. But to make your own, just get some 91% (or better) iso-propyl alcohol and some pure acetone and mix these in a 50/50 mixture. That stuff will work quite well.

Comment: @jonk ... I use lead solder (cheap one) and a cheap soldering device (not a station, just rightly plugged, but temperature controlled). I rather use that liquid and will search for it. No clue where I can get the iso-propyl alcohol, but I will check aliexpress or ebay for that liquid

Comment: @jonk ... that liquid, is it only for showing it better (to you for example) ? ... because it cost more than the STM32 itself :-)

Comment: @GregoryKornblum I downloaded the document (392 pages), a bit too much (seems like an industry reference), however, it seems some of my connections might be cold, reading paragraph 1.4.4 of IPC-A-610D.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Here in the US iso-propyl alcohol is very cheap and available at a grocery store. About US1$ for a liter. The acetone is sold anywhere house paints or varnishes are sold and should be no more expensive (here.)

Comment: @MichelKeijzers See, it's a good document :)

Comment: @jonk ... thanks ... I will check here (in the Netherlands) about the iso-propyl and acetone, I'm sure somewhere I can get it (but mostly we don't have the very big grocery stores like in the US). Thanks for all your explanation.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Yes it is, I will keep it as 'reference', thank you very much.

Comment: wiggle the pins close to your ear; squeeks/clicks are bad news. flashlights behind can help. you can also check the continuity of adjacent pins (there usually shouldn't be any)

Comment: @dandavis That sounds like a good test, going to try it this evening ... I'm not afraid about adjacent pins touching, that's something I very easily can see (and is good).

Comment: Do a visual inspection under high magnification. You can usually spot defective soldering. You either need a microscope or one of those high mag jeweller's glasses

Comment: I don't have a microscope, I have a magnification soldering item 'holder'  but it was really annoying to look through it during soldering, but maybe for visual inspection it might be good enough.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers most nail varnish remover contains high levels of acetone (check the label).

Comment: @TimP I found a store which sells 96% alcohol and aceton, so that should do it hopefully. I don't have time until the weekend to buy and try.

Comment: @Lundin .. Thanks about mentioning the pads, maybe I didn't took too much focus for the pads. I don't think there is tin between the pins (after an earlier visual inspection). I will check better this evening. Also I bought a second one, so I can try again (for about E 1,50 not much a big deal).

Comment: @Lundin ... I think you thought I meant the IC, but I soldered the pin headers to the pins on both sides.

Comment: Oh! Hah, nevermind then :) Those are quite trivial in comparison. I'll post an answer.

Comment: @dandavis  I wiggled and did not hear a sound, light behind it also did not show anything :-)

Comment: @jonk I bought the alcohol and aceton and spread it over the pins ... however, I got some white residue as can be seen on the last picture ...also I doubt it is now 'cleaner' than before.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers I can't see a problem there, but it could be a limitation of the lighting and my eyes? In any case, I forgot to mention something else -- a very stiff, short brush (usually on the end of a small curled aluminum tube. The stiff brush is really needed to make sure things dissolve from agitation. I then dab off the liquid with a special cloth (which I test) or else use a source of pressured air to blow it off.

Comment: @jonk ... thank you very much (sorry for my bad knowledge about soldering) ... most come from youtube videos :-)

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Did you use nail varnish remover for the acteone? If so, it may have oil in it to be kinder to nails but it might leave a residue on a PCB. It's easy to test the solvent mixture for residual matter: put a small amount on clean glass, wait for it to evaporate, and see if there is any residue.

Comment: @AndrewMorton No it's bought as (pure) aceton ... but I will do the check.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see any obviously bad solder joints on those pictures.  However, these pictures aren't great for inspecting the solder joints.  To get pictures of small things, you need to use a macro lens, good lighting, and proper exposure.

The main thing to look for is that the solder flowed.  That is best seen in the top picture.  It seems the solder wetted and flowed on both the pads and the pins, although too much solder is clearly evident on many of the joints.  Too much solder makes it hard to tell the difference between a blob that wetted and flowed over the pad, and one that is just sitting on top of the pad with a layer of flux or oxidized solder in between.

The proper procedure for hand soldering such pins is to put the iron in contact with both the pin and the pad.  The feed a *small* amount of solder into a crack between the iron and the pin.  The purpose of this little bit of solder is not to make the connection, but to provide good thermal conductivity between the soldering iron and what it's trying to solder.

After a second or two, the pin and pad should be hot enough to melt solder on their own.  Feed a bit more solder.  This should now melt easily and flow all over the pin and the pad.  Remove the iron as soon as the solder has flowed.  While the joint is cooling, make sure nothing is wiggling the two parts of the joint relative to each other.

### Added

On closer look at the third and fourth pictures, the solder joint for C15 is suspect.  At the least, the solder doesn't seem to have flowed over the whole pad.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, what exactly do you think is wrong?

Comment: I have a macro lens somewhere, so maybe I should try a better pic (not able before the weekend though, since the camera is not near me). Could I try to resolder C15 by heating it up again so it will reflow or will because of the lack of flux make it worse?) I would need solder wick instead?

Comment: @Mich: Try it and see.  Simply re-flowing what is that may work.  Otherwise, remove most of the existing solder first, then add fresh solder, which includes flux.

Comment: Thanks for the remark ... first I will check if it works (since in that case I don't change anything). Otherwise, I will try to reflow it, if that will not work solder wick + new solder. Thanks again!

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Simply heat it up and add a tiny bit of tin. Most often, fixing bad joints is merely a matter of heating it again. When doing so, some superfluous tin also end up on the tip, which is fine.

Comment: @Lundin Don't I get too much tin? I have the feeling I already used too much.

Comment: @Lundin (already answered in your comment of dannyf's answer)

Comment: @OlinLathrop C15 has indeed not much solder, I can do that again (better).

Answer (score 5):

If you use leaded tin then *none* of them should look matte. (ROHS tin is another story, such joints tend to look rather bleak even when properly soldered.) This wouldn't pass a professional examination, but might work (for a while) for indoors hobbyist purposes.

Overall looks like you use far too much tin and too little heat, several joints look fishy and "cold". Often the problem is that the pad didn't get enough heat. The iron needs to be placed so that it touches both the pad and the pin. You can let the tin quickly nudge the iron first, only to trigger the wetting. Then apply the tin for the actual joint without touching the iron.

There should be roughly enough tin to cover the hole. For professional use in tough environments, it is good if a bit of tin floats out on each side of the hole (assuming it is through-hole plated which should be the case here), to prevent corrosion over time. However, you don't need to "drown" the whole pin in tin as in those pictures - this might hide poor soldering underneath.

You should strive for something that looks like B3.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and some good tips .. I will try it again with my next one (or if the board above does not work to do some rework on this).

Answer (score 3):

You did a fine job there. Those cheap header pins are likely non copper. As such it is best to dial up the temperature a little and out some solder flux on the pins plus the holes before soldering them.

But your soldering is fine.

Comment: While I agree that the soldering appears to be adequate for the purpose, calling it a "fine" job is going too far.

Comment: It's my third soldering things on this scale (except from soldering some wires)... But I learnt from it. I don't have separate flux (except for what's already in the solder), but I ordered it to be added for next times.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers You don't need separate flux for this. With some "solder suck wire" you can remove superfluous tin. Then if you need more flux, just add a tiny bit more tin after that, to use the flux in the tin itself. Just don't heat the tin too long or all the flux will vaporize.

Comment: @Ludlin I will do that (usering solder wick), but only when needed (I mean when it doesn't work). But good to know I can use normal solder :-)

Comment: Solder wick would help but not necessary. I often just use speaker wires stripped of its plastic housing for this. Easy to hold too.

Comment: If I had to criticize your soldering, I would have dialed up the temperature a little and used less solder. Your looked a little bit too cold.  But that borserlines on nitpicking.

Comment: @dannyf Yes, I think I went a bit too quickly ... and maybe I understand why a solder station is probably better than my Chinese wall-outlet solder device :-)

Answer (score 1):

Whereas the above answers are useful, I don't think they answer the actual question:

> How can I best test if all soldering connections are ok?

Even poor solder connections might conduct fine for a while, or even indefinitely if not disturbed. The problem is that you want to have some reassurance that the connections remain good even over changing conditions of thermal expansion/contraction and vibration.

Put the board through a few cycles of heating/cooling through its rated temperature range, all the while applying a low-voltage square wave to each of the pins in question. If you see any interruption or distortion in the output, one of the connections has likely failed. Do the same procedure but rather than temperature variation, run a small motor acoustically coupled to the board, ideally trying multiple different axes of motion.

Edit: if you're trying the acoustically coupled motor, you would also want to test a range of frequencies (rotational speeds) of the motor, because the mechanical properties of the board and the solder connections will vary over this range - from "very low" ~1Hz to the high hundreds of Hz.

Comment: Interesting approach ... about the heating ... I would need to check what is possible (and not having a temperature sensor that can reach that temperature, neither something to heat it up). But the low-voltage square wave is possible. I have a servo motor and  small ac motor (very small), but haven't tried even to connect it (I'm just reading more about the cpu etc).

Comment: The heating can be as simple as putting the board in a fridge or freezer, and then taking it out and exposing it to a heat gun at some known (and safe) distance